# wpf mvvm with non dependency properties?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a small (I hope) problem. I have a wpf project and I use MVVM, but I need to set the "SelectedText" property of the textbox. The "selectedText" is not a dependency property so, I can't use bindings...
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you need to set the `SelectedText` only via the VM or does the binding have to work in both directions?

Comment: Ok, I'll post you a solution.

Comment: you can create a behavior you can bind to in your vm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you only need the value assignment from the VM to the control you could use an `AttachedProperty` like this.

```cs
public class AttachedProperties
{
    private static DependencyProperty SelectedTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedText", typeof(string),
            typeof(AttachedProperties), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnSelectedTextChanged)));

     private static void OnSelectedTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         var txtBox = d as TextBox;
         if (txtBox == null)
             return;

         txtBox.SelectedText = e.NewValue.ToString();
     }

     public static string GetSelectedText(DependencyObject dp)
     {
         if (dp == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dp");

         return (string)dp.GetValue(SelectedTextProperty);
     }

     public static void SetSelectedText(DependencyObject dp, object value)
     {
         if (dp == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dp");

         dp.SetValue(SelectedTextProperty, value);
     }
}
```

And the usage

```xml
<!-- Pls note, that in the Binding the property 'SelectedText' on the VM is refered -->
<TextBox someNs:AttachedProperties.SelectedText="{Binding SelectedText}" />
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are you adding a fail check, which throws an exception, to protect from letting c# throw an exception? For me it looks like the only reason is to have an ArgumentNullException instead of a NullReferenceException at the expense of writing more code, but with a proper IDE or even just the call stack it should be quiet obvious.

Comment: Well since the method is public, you should always implement it in that or a similar way, so that it can run correctly. At least this is something, that I learned through the years. IMHO it should always be done like this, because you don't know, who is using this method in future and you don't know how he is trying to use it. So you can run into an undefined state by letting the code raise the `NullReferenceException` or you raise a more specific and intented exception.